# Does using refiled toners cancel guarantee for printer?

Tags: hp-laserjet, toner

I have HP LaserJet Pro MFP M521dw. 
It is much economical for me to use refiled toners(and also repaired at the same time) than original ones, although some others calculations may prove different.
I want to know can I freely use cartridges without worry that authorized service will notice that and cancel my guarantee? (if printer ever goes to service)
Thank you!

Comment: Most likely yes, refer to the warranty for your printer.  Voting to close as off-topic (this isn't a technical problem, and we're not lawyers).

Comment: Thank you for your reply.  It's not a technical problem, just a technical question. I want to know is it possible to check what types of toners (original or reflied) were used in printer. (I assume that refiled toner is not inside the printer during check ;) Sorry for not posting clear question.

Comment: At least in the US, the manufacturer can't void the warranty simply because you used third-party supplies.  However, they won't provide support for resulting print quality issues and if the third-party toner causes a problem, that problem won't be covered by the warranty.  If there is an unrelated problem, the manufacturer might still disclaim responsibility for fixing it, which would put you in the position of having to pursue enforcement of the warranty and prove your case, which would probably be more expensive than a new printer.

Answer (score 1):

This is not really on topic here.  You really need to provide your jurisdication.  Many countries have consumer protection acts which protects your rights as long as the cartridge itself was not the cause of the warranty failure (in which case you often have rights against the cartridge maker)

In America, I believe there is a federal law - [The Magnuson-Moss Warranty Act](https://www.ftc.gov/sites/default/files/documents/public_comments/16-cfr-parts-239-700-701-702-and-703-request-comments-concerning-interpretations-magnuson-moss/00025-80835.pdf) which prevents voiding of warranties on the basis of an after-market cartridge.